# Conditions inside a C# Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, conditional-statements

I have this below script in my Class.

```
aggrgt.Add(new PlainBrgDataSummaryChartAggrgt
{
    label = m.label,
    goal = m.goal,
    groupCode = m.groupCode,
    groupValue1 = m.groupValue1,
    graphSwitch = m.graphSwitch,
    orderByAsc = m.orderByAsc,
    metricID = m.metricID,
    scoreWk1 = metricscoreWk1.metricScore1,                            
});
```

The condition I want is when `metricscoreWk1 is null, scoreWk1 = metricscoreWk1.metricScore1 is eliminated`.

Comment: It's a query defined by var.  

    var metricscoreWk1 = dataSet.Tables["dataBridge"]
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(a => Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) >= startOfWeek1 && Convert.ToDateTime(a["reportingDate"].ToString()) < endOfWeek1.AddDays(1))
                .GroupBy(a => 1)
                .Select(d => new PlainBrgDataSummaryChartAggrgt
                {
                    metricScore12 = d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("n12")) / d.Sum(a => a.Field<double?>("d12"))           
                    
                }
                ).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put `""` for `Double`, the closest analogue, INHO, is `Double.NaN` (*Not A Number*):

```
  // Let's have Double.NaN for unknown/undefined etc. value
  scoreWk1 = metricscoreWk1.metricScore1 ?? Double.NaN;
```

Answer (score 3):

This may help you:

```
scoreWk1 = metricscoreWk1.metricScore1 ==null ? 0 : metricscoreWk1.metricScore1
```

That is, if the value of `metricscoreWk1.metricScore1` is null `0`(*or else any default value*) will be assigned else the original value will be assigned to  `scoreWk1`

Comment: it works on this - scoreWk1 = metricscoreWk1 ==null ? 0:metricscoreWk1.metricScore1,  but what I want is when It's null I want the result to  be blank ("") but currently the type is double

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Create the `PlainBrgDataSummaryChartAggrgt` object without setting the `scoreWk1` field. If `metricscoreWk1` is not null, you then set the field and you then add the object to the list.
- If you have a `setter` for `metricScore1`, you could add a check wherein you ensure that `metricscoreWk1` is not `null`. If it is, the value is not updated.

The second option would allow you to keep your current initialization structure, but the first is more explicit. Should you opt for the second approach, I'd recommend you document it.

Comment: public double? scoreWk1 { get; set; }

Comment: @BotSundi: try like so: `public double scoreWk1; public double? ScoreWk1 { get {return this.scoreWk1;} set{if (this.metricscoreWk1 != null) this.scoreWk1 = value;} }`.